# Update TABLE1 on the basis of concomitant rows on TABLE2

Tags: mysql

I have a table documenting the amount of time users used products (TABLE1). Due to a historical hiccup, the time data in TABLE1 is not always up to date and may be too low. I would like to update TABLE1 with the values stored in another table (TABLE2), but only if the amount of time documented for the relevant user and the relevant product in TABLE2 is greater than the amount of time documented in TABLE1.

TABLE1

```
UserID | Product | MinutesUsed
1      | 1000    | 30
1      | 2000    | 50
1      | 3000    | 10
2      | 1000    | 20
2      | 4000    | 30
3      | 3000    | 60
```

TABLE2

```
UserID | Product | MinutesUsed
1      | 1000    | 70
1      | 2000    | 50
1      | 3000    | 10
2      | 1000    | 20
2      | 4000    | 30
3      | 3000    | 90
```

My desired UPDATE query is one that will update TABLE1 so that the data stored for all users is altered in accordance with their concomitant values in TABLE2, subject to the condition noted above:

TABLE1

```
UserID | Product | MinutesUsed
1      | 1000    | 30->70
1      | 2000    | 50
1      | 3000    | 10
2      | 1000    | 20
2      | 4000    | 30
3      | 3000    | 60->90
```

I tried the following query, but it didn't work:

```
UPDATE `TABLE1` AS t1, (SELECT UserID, Product, MinutesUsed FROM `TABLE2`) AS t2
SET t1.MinutesUsed = t2.MinutesUsed
WHERE (t1.UserID = t2.UserID) AND (t2.MinutesUsed > t1.MinutesUsed)
```

I will be happy to know what I did wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: adding expected results to the question would help for sure or is the last TABLE ascii data table the expected result?   if that ts the case then @TimBiegeleisen answer should be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want an update join here:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID AND
       t1.Product = t2.Product
SET
    t1.MinutesUsed = t2.MinutesUsed
WHERE
    t2.MinutesUsed > t1.MinutesUsed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You were lucky that you had the same product and UserID in the 2 tables. There had to be a unique primary key that helps you bind the tables to the join.

`update table1 t1
     join table2 t2 
       ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID AND
         t1.Product = t2.Product
      set t1.MinutesUsed = case
                    when t2.MinutesUsed = t1.MinutesUsed then t1.MinutesUsed
                    when t2.MinutesUsed > t1.MinutesUsed then t2.MinutesUsed
                    ELSE t1.MinutesUsed end ;`